# how to print list skipping one element each time in python without numpy?

Tags: python, list, numpy

given

```
samplelist = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]
```

then I want output as below:

```
[100,[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[101,[100,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[102,[100,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
```

Note: In the first line of output 100 is skipped i.e. `list[0]`, then in second line `list[1]` is skipped.

I tried popping and displaying but next time it is not showing all the elements that's popped. so I tried inserting them in loop end again but no luck.

Comment: Update:
Output like:
[100,[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[101,[100,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[102,[100,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]

Answer (score 4):

a simple list comprehension should do it

```
>>> samplelist = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]
>>> [[el for el in samplelist if el is not i] for i in samplelist]
[[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]]
```

Basically it scans the list and for each element it produces the whole list excluding the current element.

Alternatively, you can use a generator expression

```
>>> g = ([el for el in samplelist if el is not i] for i in samplelist)
>>> for x in g:
...     print(x)
... 
[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]
```

EDIT as per your new requirements (i.e. the skipped element must be included):

```
>>> g = ([i, [el for el in samplelist if el is not i]] for i in samplelist)
>>> for x in g:
...     print(x)
... 
[100, [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[101, [100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[102, [100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[103, [100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[104, [100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[105, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[106, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109]]
[107, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109]]
[108, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109]]
[109, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]]
```

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. What will be the change needed to print [100, [101, 102, 103..]] and so on?
I mean I want the skipped value in front separately followed by remaining list.

Comment: ahem.. this is turning into an agile practice, your requirements have changed! Please see my edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple slicing within a list comprehension :

```
>>> [samplelist[:i]+samplelist[i+1:] for i,_ in enumerate(samplelist)]
[[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109],
 [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]]
```

If you want to capture the omitted item :

```
>>> [[samplelist[i],samplelist[:i]+samplelist[i+1:]] for i,_ in enumerate(samplelist)]
[[100, [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]], [101, [100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]], [102, [100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]], [103, [100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]], [104, [100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]], [105, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109]], [106, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109]], [107, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109]], [108, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109]], [109, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]]]
```

Comment: [100,[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[101,[100,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]] 
[102,[100,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
Can you hep me like this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `itertools.combinations()`:

```
import itertools
a = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]
list(itertools.combinations(a, len(a)-1))[::-1]
```