# How to print list skipping one element each time in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
samplelist = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]
```

then I want output as below:

```
[100,[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[101,[100,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
[102,[100,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
```

With help of others here I was able to generate

```
[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
```

with following code:

```
[[el for el in samplelist if el is not i] for i in samplelist]
```

but I want that number skipped also in front as shown above.
Please suggest changes to that code.

Comment: Link to earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194974/how-to-print-list-skipping-one-element-each-time-in-python-without-numpy

Comment: Why did you ask the same question 3 hours apart? If the first question wasn't getting good answers, you should edit the question to make it clearer, not post an identical question.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a nested list with a list comprehension too:

```
>>> samplelist = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
>>> newlist = [[item, [el for el in samplelist if el != item]] for item in samplelist]
>>> for item in newlist:
...     print(item)
... 
[100, [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[101, [100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[102, [100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[103, [100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[104, [100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[105, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109]]
[106, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109]]
[107, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109]]
[108, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109]]
[109, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]]
```

BTW, you should use `==` for comparing values, not `is`. The latter is used for checking object's identity. In fact, your code only works because Python caches small integers, which is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, just add the element 'i':

```
>>> import pprint
>>> x = [[i,[el for el in samplelist if el is not i]] for i in samplelist]
>>> pprint.pprint(x)
[[100, [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]],
[101, [100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]],
[102, [100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]],
[103, [100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]],
[104, [100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]],
[105, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109]],
[106, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109]],
[107, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109]],
[108, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109]],
[109, [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print [[i]+[el for el in samplelist if el is not i] for i in samplelist]
```

works?